# Scrape - How To Get Tag For Each Row

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

In this webpage I want to scrape the title and the URL for each row.

The tag for each row seems to be <**div**> but since there are a lot of divs, how do I ensure I am pulling the right one?

Screenshot of the multiple pages/articles attached
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mPXS.png

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


productlinks=[]
url='https://journals.lww.com/ccmjournal/toc/2022/01001'


r=requests.get(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
content=soup.find_all('div')
for item in content:
    title=item.find('Title')
    link=item.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you also want top two rows and not just the numbered articles you can use an attribute = value css selector with starts with operator to target the parent div element (for all listings), with id starting with `itemListContainer`, then specifically target the direct anchor tag children of h4 elements

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://journals.lww.com/ccmjournal/toc/2022/01001')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
d = {i.text.strip():i['href'] for i in soup.select('[id^=itemListContainer] h4 > a')}
```

You can restrict to only numbered items with

```
d = {i.text.strip():i['href'] for i in soup.select('.ej-toc-subheader + div h4 > a')}
```

The class selector gets you to the subheaders then the adjacent sibling combinator moves you, along with the type selector, to the immediately adjacent div. The `h4` with child combinator (`>`) then `a` type selector  takes you to the target anchor tags.

If you want all results then you can set results to 100 per page then click next whilst that element is present. Use a pause to avoid being rate-limited:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
import time

d = webdriver.Chrome()

d.get('https://journals.lww.com/ccmjournal/toc/2022/01001')
results = {}

try:
    d.find_element_by_css_selector('.cookie-jar-content .button').click()
except:
    pass
    
d.find_element_by_css_selector('.js-items-on-page-selectize [value="100"]').click()
    
while True:
    soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')
    
    for i in soup.select('.ej-toc-subheader + div h4 > a'):
        results[i.text.strip()] = i['href'] 
     
    next_page = soup.select_one('.element__nav--next')      
    
    if next_page is None:
        break
    d.find_element_by_css_selector('.element__nav--next').click()
    time.sleep(1) # rate-limit
```

---

Just with selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

d = webdriver.Chrome()

d.get('https://journals.lww.com/ccmjournal/toc/2022/01001')
results = {}

try:
    d.find_element_by_css_selector('.cookie-jar-content .button').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
    
d.find_element_by_css_selector('.js-items-on-page-selectize [value="100"]').click()
    
while True:

    for i in d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.ej-toc-subheader + div h4 > a'):
        results[i.text.strip()] = i.get_attribute('href') 
     
    try:
        next_page = d.find_element_by_css_selector('.element__nav--next')    
    
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
                
    next_page.click()
    time.sleep(1) # rate-limit
d.close()
```

Comment: This works great thanks ! Is there a way to use this for all the pages on this site? I dont know how to do pagination w this code :l

Comment: Clicking the next page doesnt give me a unique url, so i wouldnt be able to repeat this with the next page url

Comment: This gives you all the results. 134 article links + the two start links  (the 5 pages worth)

Comment: You can then do `for k, v in d.items():` to loop the titles and links, or just `for v in d.values()` to loop the urls

Comment: The amount of pages looks like it exceeds 5. I am seeing over 1500 article links @QHarr  will post screenshot on original post

Comment: Oh...so will look

Comment: thanks, posted link to pic :)

Comment: I added selenium code. You can likely do just with bs4 and requests however.

Comment: i seem to get an error with both codes after the first page. do you get this as well?

Comment: line 28, in <module> d.find_element_by_css_selector('.element__nav--next').click()  Message: element not visible

Comment: No I did not. I might add in wait condition or maximize window

Comment: e.g. `next_page = d.find_element_by_css_selector('.element__nav--next')   :d.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", next_page)`

Comment: This is not working for me... :(   is it possible to send me output ? @QHarr

Comment: https://filebin.net/t2y9ccs8p5dqudqq

Comment: ^^output sent above

Comment: sorry, overflow site was down earlier. Thank you so much, it is great !